# How to smoothly decrease the height of a div on scroll down and increase it at the same rate on scroll up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

Here is what I have so far.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>

<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
```

CSS

```
div {

position:fixed;
top:10px;
left:10px;
width:200px;
height:400px;
background-color:red;

}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $("div").height();
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        $(window).scroll(function(event) {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(st > lastScrollTop) {
                height = height - 1;
                $("div").css({
                    'height': height
                });
            } else {
                height = height + 1;
                $("div").css({
                    'height': height
                });
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a codepen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBaVvB.

I don't know what the problem is. The logic seems so solid!

But sometimes its height decreases a lot faster than it increases or vice versa. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the onscroll, onmousemove etc. events can be a bit dicey for smooth movements as they ONLY fire as the event is triggered. These are challenging because sometimes they fire quickly, sometimes slowly BUT they don't continue after.

```
    div {
      position:fixed;
      top:10px;
      left:10px;
      width:200px;
      height:400px;
      background-color:red;
    }
```

and

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var height=oheight = $("div").height();
    $(document).scroll(function() {
         height=$(this).scrollTop()/($(document).height()-$(window).height())*oheight;
         $("div").css({
            'height': height
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: I got your point but your script didn't help, this codepen contains your script. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBaVvB

Comment: I need this because I am trying to create a slider like https://dzzynr.com/ whose height decreases when you scroll down.

Comment: idk what that means

Comment: Updated my post - is that closer to what you're after? All the best!

Comment: Sorry I took too long to respond, and sorry I can't upvote your efforts, (I don't have enough reputation points to do that), check this out, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBBezb. You have managed to make the height change effect "smooth", but there something weird about it, if I scroll up/down quickly the height increases/decreases very slowly, If I do so slowly, the height change is significant. Its pretty cool but not suitable for my slider.

Comment: Do you think this can be done? meaby the dzzynr.com people used a different logic all-together.

Comment: That's the problem with adjusting a variable height by a fixed number (in this case, 5). Your best bet would be to adjust the elements height relative to the actual distance scrolled on the page - some simple maths can do this. Im busy at the moment, can get to it later if no one else does.

Comment: I thought that was what I was already doing, take your time, no problem, but again not really sure what you mean. I'll google your words though. hopefully find something useful.

Comment: I have updated the code to show a relative height - this is more the direct I would go (and what I was eluding to earlier). Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: its almost perfect except that that the height is increasing instead of decreasing on scroll down and decreasing instead of increasing on scroll up. But you have done enough, I'll find a way to edit it myself to my needs. Thank you very much for being the only one to respond to my question. I am a muslim so may Allah shower numerous blessings upon you.